# Adding a paged ui scroll view on top of another ui scroll view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I'm have a vertical scroll and I want to add a paged scroll view on top of it to go through a set of pictures. I have both of scroll views set up through the interface builder. 
For the vertical scroll I have the following where scroll is the UIScrollView

```
-(void)createScroll{
[scroll setScrollEnabled:YES];
[scroll setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 1325)];
}
```

For the paged scroll I have the following where scrollView is the UIScrollView

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.count; i++) {
    CGRect frame;
    frame.origin.x = self.scrollView.frame.size.width * i;
    frame.origin.y = 0;
    frame.size = self.scrollView.frame.size;

    UIView *subview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    subview.backgroundColor = [array objectAtIndex:i];
    [self.scrollView addSubview:subview];

}

self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.scrollView.frame.size.width * array.count, self.scrollView.frame.size.height);

self.pageControl.currentPage = 0;
self.pageControl.numberOfPages = array.count;
```

The problem is that the images are not showing up in the paged scroll view. I put the paged scroll into a single view test app and it works fine, however it doesn't work when I add it on top of the vertical scroll. I have a feeling that it has something to do with adding it to the subview, but I'm new to obj-c and not sure what order the subviews should go in. Anybody have any advice? Cheers!

Comment: First, make sure that the horizontal paging scroll view is a subview of the vertical one. In interface builder, it may be possible that the vertical one is on top of the horizontal one. Second, check to see if your array is not empty.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. The issue was that I was creating the scroll view in the viewDidLoad method. Once I changed it to (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated it worked fine. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was creating the scroll view in the viewDidLoadMethod, once I created it in the (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated method the scroll views worked perfectly.